# Angular Routing on Server Page refresh getting 404.0 error

Tags: angular, server, routes, page-refresh

I am using angular 7 in my project. Below is the routing details

app.routing-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Test1Component } from './test1/test1.component';
import { Test2Component } from './test2/test2.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'test1', component:Test1Component},
  {path:'test2', component:Test2Component}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Test1Component } from './test1/test1.component';
import { Test2Component } from './test2/test2.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Test1Component,
    Test2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

On Page refresh in a server, getting 404 error.
Using HostingHosting Raja Windows server.

Sample Code http://project15.in

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

[Angular io deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)

You need to add an web.config with url rewrite rule or use hashlocationstrategy as described by Ankit Prajapati.